# Unable to log into administrator section of Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-2.5, administrator

Had a site up and running fine last night and today when I try to log in to the admin section it just send me straight back to the administrator log in page, no errors about incorrect username or anything, its like its stuck in a loop.

I've done my share of googling and have tried

- ensuring all user and authentication plugins are enabled
- deleting all sessions from the sessions table
- making sure there is nothing in the cookies fields in the configuration.php
- setting the sessions handler in the configuration.php to none

Front end of the site seems to work fine although I have noticed one anomaly,  on an internal page images aren't showing, it failing to load the url. On the homepage however they load fine....

Comment: Are cookies (and JavaScript) enabled in your browser? Have you tried accessing your site in "private browsing" mode to ensure that any local cookies/cache are not interfering? Tried a different browser?

Comment: This could be a session error. Have you got a chance to access the database and empty the sessions?

Comment: Have you checked error.log for any errors?

Comment: Have you changed something on you .htaccess file?

Comment: @pepLainez - Im currently not using the .htaccess file (eg its still htaccess.txt)

Comment: @jackJoe I've tried clearing the sessions tables from the database

Comment: @w3d have tried various browsers and in private mode to no avail.

Comment: do you have a frontend login page or module published? Will it allow you to login via the front end?

Comment: Sometimes it is connected with the session.save_path. And you did not answer - are there any errors in the servers's error.log file?

Comment: Is it publicly visible, the URL might help us track down the problem.

Comment: @dmitryRekun I've had a squiz in the log files and they dont seem to contain anything.  For the session.save_path do I contact my hosts? Im just miffed as to why it suddenly started happening

Comment: @toniMarie no front end login module published unfortunantly. Theoretically I could create one via the database I guess...

Comment: @cppl I'll post you the address via email, rather not put it out in the public domain. PS Gday from Albury

Comment: @rowanwins just to be sure - is it server's error file where all fatal errors are located? About `session.save_path` - just guessing and not sure since you can login from frontend.

Comment: You said "setting the sessions handler in the configuration.php to none" . Try to set it to 'database'

Answer (score 2):

I think you have accidentally unpublished the Joomla User plugin. Using phpMyAdmin, or whatever tool your host provides for you to access your database, look in the xxxxx_extensions table for plg_user_joomla. The "enabled" field should have a value of 1. If it's 0 or something else change it to 1 and try logging in again.

Comment: Hi John, yep I'd already checked that and no joy sorry.

Comment: Hi John! Next time please read more carefully the question asked. Author already wrote in it that he have checked the plugins. Thank you.

Comment: He did, but in an abstract meaningless way. When describing a problematic situation you need to provide specific information. Stating enabling all user and authentication plugins doesn't mean the plg_user_joomla is enabled, how to know it is available. Could have been removed!

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the options I found across the various forums and blogs I ended up setting up a fresh install of joomla 2.5 and basically reinstalling all my extensions and then copying what I could from the old database (eg articles, menus, module settings etc).

To get the site back up and running to a reasonable state using this method took a couple of hours but that was less time than I spent googling and tring random solutions which didn't work!

Thanks for all your suggestions.